# Directory traversal fix for nginx config

Tags: nginx, security, web-server

I discovered that my website has this issue and I wasn't able to fix this. I tried several things like to checking if parent prefixed locations for Nginx alias directives end with a directory separator , but no luck so far. Merge_slashes on - is the default setting. I've read about AppArmour or SELinux. Is that the way to go? I have Ubuntu 18. In other words, I'm able to download this file http://example.com///etc/passwd and I want to avoid this. Any help is appreciate. Here is my config:

```
         server {
  listen 80;
  server_name
    .example.com;

 return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

server_name
  www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers '......
    ssl_certificate          /...crt;
    ssl_certificate_key      /..key;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {

server_name
  example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers '...
    ssl_certificate          /...crt;
    ssl_certificate_key      /.....key;

    add_header x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header x-xss-protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; $

    root /var/www/www.example.com;
    index index.php;

  client_max_body_size 10M;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log error;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location /shopping/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        rewrite ^/shop/wp-json/(.*?)$ /shopping/index.php?rest_route=/$1 last;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /shop/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 24h;
        log_not_found off;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;

 }
location ~\.(log|save|htaccess|json|csv|txt|xls)$ {
     deny all;
     error_page 403 =404 / ;
 }
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
}
```

Comment: Your issue is in your PHP application not in `nginx`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? It will be much appreciated!

Comment: The request to `//etc/passwd` would match `location '/'` and unless you have a file `/var/www/www.example.com/etc/passwd` it would be handled by `index.php` through `fastcgi_pass`.

Comment: SELinux is designed to prevent exactly this on RHEL systems. I'm not as familiar with AppArmor. Effectively SELinux only allows a process to access things that match their context. It would mitigate this issue, but @AlexD is right - the issue is with the PHP app.

Comment: For some mysterious reason, some directories were copied to the website root causing this  /var/www/ www.example.com/etc/passwd  My bad that I did not discovered this earlier!

Comment: in case you solved your issue please add an answer and accept it later on, else we will be remembered until the of universe on it

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with nginx config. Some dev guy created in a mysterious way a copy of `/ect/passw` into  `/var/www/www.example.com/etc/passwd` So that why I could browse/download it and that why my PCI scanner was failing. Sorry for taking your time!