# Directory traversal fix for nginx config

Tags: nginx

I discovered that my website has this issue and I wasn't able to fix this. I
tried several things like to checking if parent prefixed locations for Nginx alias directives end with a directory separator , but no luck so far. Merge_slashes  on - is the default setting. I've read about AppArmour or SELinux. Is that the way to go? I have Ubuntu 18.
In other words, I'm able to download this file
http://mywebsite.com///etc/passwd
and I want to avoid this. Any help is appreciate.
Here is my config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name
    .mysite.com;

 return 301 https://mysite.com$request_uri;
}

server {

server_name
  www.mysite.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers '......
    ssl_certificate          /...crt;
    ssl_certificate_key      /..key;

    return 301 https://mysite.com$request_uri;
}
server {

server_name
  mysite.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers '...
    ssl_certificate          /...crt;
    ssl_certificate_key      /.....key;

    add_header x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header x-xss-protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; $

    root /var/www/www.mysite.com;
    index index.php;

  client_max_body_size 10M;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.error.log error;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location /shopping/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        rewrite ^/shop/wp-json/(.*?)$ /shopping/index.php?rest_route=/$1 last;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /shop/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 24h;
        log_not_found off;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;

 }
location ~\.(log|save|htaccess|json|csv|txt|xls)$ {
     deny all;
     error_page 403 =404 / ;
 }
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a nginx configuration question than a security question.  Serverfault might be a more appropriate location.

Comment: OK, Thanks! I will post answer here if I will find it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Directory traversal fix for nginx config](https://serverfault.com/questions/1087875/directory-traversal-fix-for-nginx-config)